# how to read file line by line and delete the line have number less than 20% shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell-script, numeric-data

i need help.
i have this file 
i want read it line by line with for loops and delete the line less than 20% the number will with list %CPU .

```
%CPU   PID USER       UID COMMAND         %MEM
71  9136 ashti     1000 firefox          4.6
36  1432 ashti     1000 gnome-shell      8.6
25 9100 ashti     1000 gedit            1.1
 3  9092 ashti     1000 nautilus         1.2
 2  9109 ashti     1000 gnome-terminal-  0.9
 1 1248 ashti     1000 Xorg             2.6
 0  1375 ashti     1000 VBoxClient       0.0
 0  9118 ashti     1000 bash             0.1
 0   269 root         0 systemd-journal  2.8
```

i want be like this example

```
%CPU   PID USER       UID COMMAND         %MEM
71  9136 ashti     1000 firefox          4.6
36  1432 ashti     1000 gnome-shell      8.6
25 9100 ashti     1000 gedit            1.1
```

and save in new file .

best regards

Comment: why are you requiring the use of a `for loop`?

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: please check this link its my code question

[link] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549368/i-need-help-i-have-this-code-i-want-add-if-the-number-of-c-grater-than-2-pri)

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu you can post these questions in [**Ask Ubuntu**](https://askubuntu.com/)  What command did you use to generate the CPU%? It appears like it needs to be divided by the number of CPU cores for an accurate percentage.

Answer (score 2):

With `grep`:

```
grep -e "^%" -e "^[2-9][1-9]" file | column -t
```

`column -t` to make it pretty:

```
%CPU  PID   USER   UID   COMMAND      %MEM
71    9136  ashti  1000  firefox      4.6
36    1432  ashti  1000  gnome-shell  8.6
25    9100  ashti  1000  gedit        1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

With retaining header, `awk` expression:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || (NR > 1 && $1 > 20)' file
%CPU   PID USER       UID COMMAND         %MEM
71  9136 ashti     1000 firefox          4.6
36  1432 ashti     1000 gnome-shell      8.6
25 9100 ashti     1000 gedit            1.1
```

Comment: please check this link its my code question

[link] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549368/i-need-help-i-have-this-code-i-want-add-if-the-number-of-c-grater-than-2-pri)

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop is not a good choice for this task - for a discussion of the reasons why, see for example

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

My personal choice would be Miller:

```
$ mlr --pprint filter -x '${%CPU} < 20' file > newfile

$ cat newfile
%CPU PID  USER  UID  COMMAND     %MEM
71   9136 ashti 1000 firefox     4.6
36   1432 ashti 1000 gnome-shell 8.6
25   9100 ashti 1000 gedit       1.1
```

Comment: please check this link its my code question

[link] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549368/i-need-help-i-have-this-code-i-want-add-if-the-number-of-c-grater-than-2-pri)